# Зачем нужен NPM если есть ресурс на CDN?

Tags: javascript, library, cdn

Подскажите, зачем нужен NPM если есть ресурс на CDN?
К примеру, хочу использовать какую-то библиотеку.
По инструкции, могу установить через NPM, а могу воспользоваться CDN.

В первом случае:

1. Надо установить Node.js (если не установлен еще NPM)
2. Установить библиотеку, написав команду в командной строке
3. Как я понял, создать спец файл в директории проекта, где подключить библиотеку методом require.

При этом:

- мы не сможем сбросить свой проект в какую-нибудь песочницу типа Codepen, т.к. библиотека не будет включена в выкладываемые файлы
- грузим сервер этой библиотекой

Во втором случае:

1. Просто подключить скрипт с адресом.

При этом:

- грузим клиента этой библиотекой

Если это действительно так, но на кой нам вообще заморачиваться с NPM в случае не крупных библиотек? Или я чего-то не улавливаю/не принимаю в расчет? Прошу объяснить все не указанные мною плюсы и минусы обоих подходов.

Comment: по Вашему весь мир подключен к глобальной сети?

Comment: да, забыл это указать, что случаи локальной сети я не рассматриваю.

А что, только для этого существует NPM?

Comment: более того, мир `js` не ограничивается только браузером) Есть тот же `nodejs`

Comment: Убедительно прошу объяснить все не указанные мною плюсы и минусы обоих подходов.

Comment: одно - менеджер пакетов для управления зависимостями от вендоров, другое - способ хранить статику в облаке поближе к клиенту. примерно как бензин и машина. зачем вам бензин, если можно просто поехать на машине?

Comment: PolYarBear — новый участник сайта. Будьте снисходительны, задавая уточняющие вопросы, комментируя и отвечая))

это если наведете на абзац "Новый участник".
можете объяснить более доходчиво для чайника?

Comment: @PolYarBear когда у вас в проекте станет более 10 сторонних библиотек, тогда вы почувствуете, что вручную контролировать версии пакетов и их зависимостей становится сложновато

Comment: речь идет только о работе в браузере при подключенном интернете. Ну, при этом интернет, скажем, от 10 Мбит в секунду. В таком случае имеет смысл работать с библиотеками типа jQuery, Chart.js, которые в сжатом виде весят 200кб, через NPM?

Comment: @PolYarBear если у вас только 2 эти библиотеки и у них нет зависимостей, то, возможно и не стоит. Только учтите, что при деплое версии могут измениться (если вы, например, ссылаетесь на latest версии этих библиотек на CDN) и проект рискует стать нерабочим в продакшн

Comment: @PolYarBear в общем случае, проблемы выявятся позже, можете не сомневаться. Вот только масштибировать приложение, изначально с зазором на масштабируемость не построенное, поверьте, будет тяжело. Поэтому лучше изначально потратить пускай день на настройку окружения, но зато сохранить себе время и нервы потом.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, не знаю, как отблагодарить комментарий лайком. А не подскажете, есть ли видео какое-нибудь, где именно на такие вопросы даны ответы? потому что все видео, которые я смотрел, никогда и нигде не доходят до таких, видимо, тупых вопросов, и не сравнивают NPM c CDN

Comment: @PolYarBear "лайки" на комметариях здесь ничего не дают (даже репутации), а лишь позволяют отображать комментарий, даже когда комментарии свернуты, поэтому, можете не заморачиться :) Видео, к сожалению, не подскажу. Вопрос, на самом деле, с какой-то стороны вполне резонный. По большому счету CDN - это способ распространения тех же npm-пакетов в уже собранном виде (например, для быстрого прототипирования, когда лень настраивать среду со сборщиками, транспиляторами и т.п.).

Comment: @PolYarBear не уверен на 100%, но уверен примерно на 99% что CDN сборка того же JQuery происходит в автоматическом режиме путем загрузки на этот CDN файлов, собранных тем же способом, что и для NPM.

Comment: весь риск ссылок на CDN, когда вдруг он станет недоступен. Проблемы вышестоящий провайдеров у клиента, или например Роскомназдор опять решить банить адреса миллионами. Если у вас проект с парой библиотек, которые вы в целом не планируете обновлять в дальнейшем, нет смысла использовать пакетные менеджеры. С другой стороны, у клиента эти библиотеки все равно будет кешироваться, так что какой-то большой нагрузки храние их у себя тоже не создаст. но и тут без менеджеров.

Comment: И да, не стоит забывать, что NPM изначально проектировался как пакетный менеджер для *node*, а не для браузера. Для ноуда хоть и можно тоже с CDN подгрузить зависимости, но это уже будут костыли. В какой-то степени даже использовангие npm для браузерного кода является (являлось) костылем, но это уже в любом случае стало не то что нормой, а стандартом

Comment: Ясно теперь, спасибо всем за ответы! Но вот еще вопрос вылез: к примеру, я сделал проект с зависимостями, которые были установлены через NPM глобально (т.е. их нет в папке проекта, как я понимаю), проект этот вел на github. Теперь человек скачивает этот проект. Но NPM у него не установлен. Значит ли это, что у человека проект не запустится? Как ему понять, что делать? Лезть в файл package.json? А если в том же dependencies в package.json не указан необходимый пакет? Или по умолчанию всё подгрузится в репозиторий?